# Generating Google Pay Token without UI

Tags: google-pay

We have a use-case where we need to authorize a payment using a native payment on the web but use two different merchants. We want the user to press pay with Google and go through the ui but access google pay api with two different merchants. `paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest).then(function(paymentData){ // if using gateway tokenization, pass this token without modification paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token; }).catch(function(err){ // show error in developer console for debugging console.error(err); });`
is it possible to get the callback from this api request without a user interaction for the second request.

Comment: This isn't possible. I'd be interested to understand your use case better. If it is for the purpose of say charging a commission, I think you are better off collecting the payment with a single merchant, and then separately making a transaction from that merchant to the other. You might even want to aggregate and batch process the transaction to the other merchant.

Comment: That is the approach we will be taking. Thank you for your response.